# Error Starting Protocol Stack: Invalid arguement

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I am currently trying to work with the `geth` and I want to start my private Ethereum Network so I can test my applications. However, when I try to use `geth --datadir=./chaindata/` but that's only giving me some error in the terminal which I have shown at the bottom of this question. I am aware that there are other users that are having the same problem on Mac OS, which is what I'm using as well.

Here is the terminal output:

```
Steves-MBP:assignment_1 stevesahayadarlin$ geth --datadir=./chaindata/
WARN [01-06|22:12:18] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default 
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/stevesahayadarlin/Desktop/distributed_exchange_truffle_class_3-master/assignment_1/chaindata/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 15 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: <nil> Engine: unknown}"
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/stevesahayadarlin/Desktop/distributed_exchange_truffle_class_3-master/assignment_1/chaindata/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/stevesahayadarlin/.ethash                                                                                count=2
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=9b8d4a…9021ba td=131072
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=9b8d4a…9021ba td=131072
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=9b8d4a…9021ba td=131072
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [01-06|22:12:18] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] UDP listener up                          self=enode://258e1a8136fd23d47b97404139841059a37e95751182dde366adc4a22bab88b9580eb53bfb1de937016645817f071d0766a3be66e7e056c8f6afe0a450bb221d@70.106.232.168:30303
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://258e1a8136fd23d47b97404139841059a37e95751182dde366adc4a22bab88b9580eb53bfb1de937016645817f071d0766a3be66e7e056c8f6afe0a450bb221d@70.106.232.168:30303
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Blockchain manager stopped 
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Stopping Ethereum protocol 
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Ethereum protocol stopped 
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Transaction pool stopped 
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Database closed                          database=/Users/stevesahayadarlin/Desktop/distributed_exchange_truffle_class_3-master/assignment_1/chaindata/geth/chaindata
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
INFO [01-06|22:12:20] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen unix /Users/stevesahayadarlin/Desktop/distributed_exchange_truffle_class_3-master/assignment_1/chaindata/geth.ipc: bind: invalid argument
Steves-MBP:assignment_1 stevesahayadarlin$
```

Comment: Odd error...Do you have another instance of `geth` running or have something else running on port 30303? Do you still get this error if you try running on a different port or by using `—rpc`? Also, FYI, you’re connecting to mainnet (network id = 1)

Comment: @AdamKipnis I've tried killing the other instance of geth and i would still get the same error. Do you know how I can try running on a diff port or even how to use -rpc?

Comment: @AdamKipnis and anything wrong with connecting to mainnet?

Comment: They are CL options. See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options. Nothing wrong with connecting to mainnet. I only mention that because you said you wanted to “start my private Ethereum Network”. Assumed that meant a private blockchain. I guess you meant run a local node instead? If so, then mainnet is fine.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I tried using -rpc and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I dont know what I did but I restarted my computer and it seems to work fine.